# FileOutputStream wait for finishing writing

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

I have many byte[] pieces to write to a file and these pieces are kinda big and I think the bytes are getting mixed...

Is there any methods to wait for .write(byte[]) to finish his work or other ways to deal with this problem? 
When I watch the file the first half is ok , then when I start writing the second half, some time it ends with the first half.... The byte array is good, I tested them.
If you need any explain of code feel free ask.

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Main.newFile)) {
        for (int y = 0; y < piecesCount; y++) {
            if (this.myList[y] == 1) {
                fos.write(this.piecesArray.get(y).piece);
                fos.flush();
                System.out.println("Im writing " + y + " piece");
            } else {
                y--;
            }
        }
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to fos.close() when you use the try with resourcesstatement

Comment: Okay , thanks for advice!

Comment: I think you're saying that you suspect the calls to `fos.write` are not occurring sequentially.  Rest assured, they are.  And you can get rid of that `fos.flush()` call, it serves no purpose except to slow things down.

Comment: I can certainly say that you don't need to flush the output stream to ensure the sequentiality of the written bytes.

Comment: Mmm , flush don't really changes anything , just maybe it slows ,  @VGR are you saying that there can't be any possibility that fos.write() is called when he is not finished his job?

Comment: The output of your `System.out.println` statements, should help you see which objects get written. Does this output match the order of the written file ?

Comment: Output shows order of writing correctly...

Comment: And I tested with smaller byte arrays like (20 times smaller) and like 9/10 times file was written correctly.

Comment: Correct.  There is no possibility that the call to `write` will return unless and until it has finished writing.

Comment: I am quite a bit confused about the *y* variable. How do you get out of the loop if *myList[y]* is not *1*? As far as I can see *y* is decremented and then incremented by the for loop again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if `piecesCount` is a `long` the `int y` variable may overflow and start wrtiting the first part of the array.

If this is not the case,  I don't see other bugs in this code that may cause what you described. In which case there must be something going on in

> piecesArray.get(y).piece

Comment: No, piecesCount is integer and it's never is over 1000 , so I don't think he can overflow